# Polymer 2: How to extend an element with a slot, then stamp children template in that slot?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

How would I go about extending an element that has a slot in its template, and stamp my child element’s dom in that slot?

I’m trying to override the child’s template method (like [that](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#inherited-templates)) but so far I was unsuccessful.

What I’m trying to do is extending a paper-dropdown-menu to always have a certain dropdown content, while keeping all of paper-dropdown-menu input features (validation, etc.) without wiring all by hand with a "wrapper" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way! It's just replacing the parent's slot node with the child's node you want to stamp instead, here's an example:

```html
<dom-module id="custom-child">
  <template>
    <what-you-want-to-stamp slot="parent-slot-name"></what-you-want-to-stamp>
  </template>

  <script>
    (() => {
      const CustomParent = customElements.get('custom-parent')

      let memoizedTemplate
      class CustomChild extends CustomParent {
        static get is() {
          return 'custom-child'
        }

        static get template() {
          if (!memoizedTemplate) {
            memoizedTemplate = Polymer.DomModule.import(this.is, 'template')
            let whatYouWantToStamp = memoizedTemplate.content.querySelector('what-you-want-to-stamp')

            let parentTemplateContent = document.importNode(CustomParent.template.content, true)
            let slot = parentTemplateContent.querySelector('slot')

            memoizedTemplate.content.insertBefore(parentTemplateContent, whatYouWantToStamp)
            memoizedTemplate.replaceChild(whatYouWantToStamp, slot)
          }

          return memoizedTemplate
        }
      }

      customElements.define(CustomChild.is, CustomChild)
    })()
  </script>
</dom-module>
```